# How do I import file with SQL commands?

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g

I have a simple problem, but I can't find out how to solve it.
I have a file which contains many SQL commands, like this:

```
insert into .. ;
insert into .. ;
...
```

And now is the question - how do I import it?
I was trying to import script, but it doesn't work, I'm getting:

```
Your export file is not supported
```

When I'm copying my commands manually, it's works. But I can't copy them all, it will take too long.

I'm using Oracle DB 11g XE.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a SQL interpreter for Oracle. The one that is bundled with every Oracle client installation is called [SQL*Plus](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus). And will do what you need to import a file with SQL commands.

You login with it to your Oracle server and then run your script. Let's say your Oracle connection is called **mydb** and your schema name is **scott** and your SQL script is stored in a file called **myfile.sql**. What you can do is:

```
$ sqlplus scott@mydb
```

To login to oracle (you will be prompted with your password). And then, once you are inside **SQL*Plus**, you can do:

```
> @myfile.sql
```

Done.

Comment: You'd think this would be easier to find in the Oracle documentation. StackOverflow does it again - thx!

Answer (score 3):

Use SQL*Plus or [Oracle SQL developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html).

With SQL*Plus:

```
sqlplus <schema>/<pw> @<your_script.sql>
```

With SQL Developer, open your script, and then "run as script" (<kbd>F5</kbd> I think).